# regex doesn't work for empty strings

Tags: php, regex

I would like to get the content in between of a single string, however, if the content is empty, my regex is failing...

```
<?PHP
$string = "
blaat = 'Some string with an escaped \' quote'; // some comment.
empty1 = ''; // omg! an empty string!
empty2 = ''; // omg! an empty string!
";

preg_match_all( '/(?<not>\'.*?[^\\\]\')/ims', $string, $match );

echo '<pre>';
print_r( $match['not'] );
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

This will give as output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 'Some string with an escaped \' quote'
    [1] => ''; // omg! an empty string!
empty2 = '
)
```

I know this problem can be fixed with the following regex, thought i'm looking for a true solution in stead of a fix for every exception...

```
preg_match_all( '/((\'\')|(?<not>\'(.*?[^\\\])?\'))/ims', $string, $match );
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Are you trying to parse PHP?

Comment: This regex will finally be part of a system to remove comments from files e.g. PHP, js, css, tpl, etc. The whole system works, thought i found out today that escaped quotes gave a problem. Thus i addes the [^\\\] to the regex, which causes this current problem that the empty quotes are not recognized.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to parse languages with regular expressions properly... think about nesting like quotes in comments or comment markers in strings. You'd need a tokenizer for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?PHP
$string = "
blaat = 'Some string with an escaped \' quote'; // some comment.
empty1 = ''; // omg! an empty string!
empty2 = ''; // omg! an empty string!
";

preg_match_all( '/(?<not>
    \'          #match first quote mark
    .*?         #match all characters, ungreedy
    (?<!\\\)    #use a negative lookbehind assertion
    \'
    )
/ixms', $string, $match );

echo '<pre>';
print_r( $match['not'] );
echo '</pre>';

?>
```

Worked for me. I also added the /x freespacing mode to space it out a bit and make it easier to read.

Comment: Excelence! This is exactly what I was looking for! I truely have no clue what a "negative lookbehind assertion" is, but im going to look it up right away! superb!

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$string = "
blaat = 'Some string with an escaped \' quote'; // some comment.
empty1 = ''; // omg! an empty string!
empty2 = ''; // omg! an empty string!
not_empty = 'Another non empty with \' quote'; 

";

$parts = preg_split("/[^']*'(.*)'.*|[^']+/", $string, 0, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

print_r($parts);
```

will output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Some string with an escaped \' quote
    [1] => Another non empty with \' quote
)
```